# Getting a cell value from a column based on cell value from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
d = {'Number': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7], 'Letters': ["a", "d","z","f","u","p","g"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    Number Letters
0       1       a
1       2       d
2       3       z
3       4       f
4       5       u
5       6       p
6       7       g
```

And i want to get a value from `Letters` column based on the `Number` column
Lets say i want to get the letter where the number is 3

What I did was

```
letter = df.loc[df['Number'] == 3]
dfletter = pd.DataFrame(data=letter.values, columns = ['Number', 'Letter']) 
dfletter = dfletter.drop(columns = 'Number')
```

which gives me what i want

```
    Letter
0      z
```

But this seems like a dumb workaround, so I am looking for a better solution

Answer (score 1):

```
output = df.loc[df['Number'] == 3, 'Letters']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df[df.Number == 3].Letters
2    z
Name: Letters, dtype: object
```

Or, if you really need a scalar value:

```
>>> df[df.Number == 3].Letters.values[0]
'z'
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using `loc` here?